# jQuery find closest product image

Tags: jquery, find, closest

I am trying to find product's profile picture with jQuery .

My store is located at: http://45.55.232.92/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51

And my product detail located between div's which class is **product-info**.

And example code is:

```
var img = $(this).closest('li').find('img:first');
```

How can I find my product's profile image?

Comment: Please be more specific and post more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following solve your problem

```
var img = $(".product-info").find('img:first');
```